# Connecting ACODE to Termux

Tags: ssh, termux

Hi guys I have successfully connected ACODE to termux using sftp from ACODE to termux SSH using openssh `sshd` and dropbear `dropbear` via generated password `passwd` and username `whoami` and it works. I've been trying to write nodejs codes generated outside storage directory since **storage** refuses to install **expressjs** or **reactjs**, but ssh crashes after writing few lines of code and I attempt to save the file.

Comment: I used rsync/cp to copy code back and forth from the storage a file editor can access to internal storage of the app (UserLAnd and not Termux, but same idea). Is there an actual question here? Because your post seems to only be a statement with your answer being a related statement which should've been edited into the question instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was using localhost as my connection host that's why it was crashing.  I switched to inet **IP** and it worked. You can check your **inet** configuration with `ifconfig` on termux